Natural examples of identity element and inverse element outside of numbers?
What is a more practical or human-oriented example of "identity element" and "inverse element"? We have the numbers so that x+0=x and x*1=x, and x + -x=0, but what about examples using things like colors or apples or things more human-oriented?
For "commutative", you can draw a picture of 2 apples and 3 apples, and 3 apples and 2 apples, and show 5 apples below:

You can also mix two colors in any order to get a third color.
What sorts of things on this sort of conceptual and intuitive level exist for describing inverse and identity elements?

Yeah, there's a limit where things like apples or colors can serve as examples. Or in other words, there's a reason why natural numbers are called "natural", while other are not. Did you know that the concept of negative numbers was resisted until mid 19th century?

@freakish I did know that about negative numbers! Just learned about it last week!

You should be using MathJax by now. Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

I find the integers $\Bbb Z$ very easy, very intuitive, and more practical than apples. To add $2$ apples and $3$ apples, it helps me, only to write $2+3=5$. And zero is also not easier with "no apples" for me, or more "human-oriented". Not to mention "negative apples", for the inverse of, say, two apples.

In the monoid of strings of characters under concatenation, the empty string is the identity element, though there aren’t inverses

An easy and clear one is rotations of a cube, where you pick it up out of a snugly fitting square rimmed tray, rotate it, and return it to its tray. Then, say, rotating it through 360 degrees about its upper face is the identity element (as is the “do nothing” act of rotating it through 0 degrees), while rotating it 90 degrees and rotating it 270 degrees are inverses of one another.

A very natural, highly complicated group arises as a logistic system on a shunting yard of a railway system.
As elements, it may include the translation group of $n_k$ elements on a single rail $k$ with restictions to conserve order; the transfer of the first wagon to become the first on another rail line;  and even the switch of direction of any first element.
Obviously the group of operations can by simplified by factoring out the translations and restrict it to position lists and the binary orientation of each element.
The neutral element is the 'no action', the inverse element of any ordered list of element-wise simple operations is the reversed list of inverses.
This simple example is rich enough to serve as a model of representing very abstract products of groups including even spin groups.
If you mount a  coloured n-sphere on each wagon you may include the rotation groups; if you fill the wagon with people interacting by smartphones for rearranging their seats, you have the full standard model of elementary physics.

It's a little bit beyond my conception, but I see a glimmer of hope in this! If you could provide a concrete example, listing out cases or something, that might help me even more.

To find natural examples, we've first got to be totally clear on what a neutral element is. Specifically, as you point out, it's the element that does nothing when applied to any other element.
In any real-life scenario, we have the option to not intervene, which could be thought of as a neutral element. For example, with apples, the neutral element is adding no apples into your collection. With colors, it's mixing no other color with the color you already have. The neutral element is the "do nothing" action. However, it would be better to find an example where it's obviously something you need to consider.
Example 1: Shuffling. If you have a deck of cards, you can imagine the set of possible shuffles (rearrangements). For example, one way to shuffle is to cut the deck exactly in half and recombine the two them with every other card coming from each stack. Another less exciting shuffle is to take the top card of your deck and put it on the bottom. Shuffles can be "added" by doing one shuffle and then another. The neutral element is to leave the deck in the order you found it. This needs to be included in your set because shuffles can cancel each other out. For example if $X$ is the shuffle  which puts the top card on bottom, then adding 52 copies of $X$ leaves the deck in the same order it started as.
(This is also a good example of a non-commutative group.)
Example 2: Turning your car. In this example, let's suppose you only care which direction the car is pointing. The neutral element is to not turn at all. If you turn 90° left four times in a row, you return to the same direction you were headed originally, so we have to consider not turning in the set of turns.
Example 3: Photoshop color filters. If you've used any photo-editing software, you've probably used color filters, which work by altering the colors of a photo. The neutral color filter is to not alter the colors at all. If used a filter that changes red to blue and blue to red, that can be cancelled by applying it twice, so the neutral color filter can be built as a combination of other filters, just like in the previous example. However, not every filter is invertible. For example, no filter can restore the colors after making your photo black-and-white. (This means that the space of color filters is a monoid not a group, since not every element is invertible.)
